# Code assist for javascript in HTML files not working well in Aptana 3

Tags: javascript, aptana, aptana3

I'm beginning to use Aptana3 for web development, when using javascript inside a html file I get fewer suggestions than when I work in .js file.
I took this screenshots:

HTML file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/31fn0samrk8cbbf/html.jpeg

javascript file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ej135t5k9v3w3j9/jscript.jpeg

So basically in html i get poor suggestions for javascript.

What can I do?

Comment: It is good practice to keep your js code in .js files, separate from the .html file. I would go with the flow, and not keep js code in html.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing for now, still it would be good to have the choice.

Comment: any news on this? I'm getting the same behavior.
@tomdemuyt there are cases where creating a new file or importing a big js file is an overkill, so it would be create if there is a fix about this

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the default editor for .html files to the Aptana JS Editor.

Go to `Preferences > General > Editors -> File Associations`

Then select *.html from the top list and Aptana JS Editor in the bottom list, then press the 'Default' button.

Comment: except that in latest version we cannot see this option anymore... :\

Answer (score 2):

I think that is related to JFlex (scanner generator used by Aptana) that will skip <script> inside HTML.  When I added new lexical rule the JFlex to include the <script type="application/javascript">,  Aptana Studio 3 will display JavaScript content assist inside HTML.  https://github.com/JockiHendry/aptanastudio-contentassist-patch